# Facebook og:image meta tag ignoring dynamic images from php scripts

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Anyone getting Facebook to use an og:image that points to a PHP script? Eg:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://x.com/script.php?param=123">
```

Facebook never uses the image made by my script at the content URL.

If I take the output of that script and save it to a static file and have the meta tag's content attribute point to that, Facebook will use it. Facebook doesn't even mind if I tack a query string onto the URL to the static file. I'd almost think it was rejecting anything containing '.php'. If I have the script do nothing but redirect to the static file, Facebook still ignores it.

I change all URLs on each test, so presumably caching isn't part of the problem.

Judging from my access log, Facebook does successfully get the image from the script.

Does Facebook want static files? If the latter, what can I do to make my script look like a static file? A simple .htaccess redirect from something without '.php' in the name didn't work. Anyone tried using base64 encoded data uri for og:image?

Comment: Go here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and paste the page address in the field. It should tell you why it's not using the image.

Comment: The debugger just complains that the image has to be at least 200x200 even though my script's output is exactly that size. Where my image should appear in the debug results is blank, but if I click on the blank space my dynamic image does popup. Obviously Facebook has the correct URL but has some weird issue showing it.

Comment: Ok can you post the URLs of both the static and dynamic images that you're trying?